# How to merge elements of atomic vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I wanted to merge different elements of atomic vectors by elements names stored in list. See example:

```
ls = list(a = c(a = 1, b = 2, d = 2), b = c(b = 2, c = 3), c = c(a = 1, b = 2))
```

Now, I wanted to get output like this:

```
   a  b  c
a  1  NA 1
b  2  2  2
c  NA 3  NA
d  2  NA NA
```

I tried `Reduce`, but it is not working. I do not want to use any external package for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[` in `sapply` after you have extracted all elements names.

```
i <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(ls, names))))
x <- sapply(ls, "[", i)
rownames(x) <- i
x
#   a  b  c
#a  1 NA  1
#b  2  2  2
#c NA  3 NA
#d  2 NA NA
```

Comment: It means, there is no direct way of doing this. We have to first get all elements names, and then get elements for each using subsetting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `bind_rows` here

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
bind_rows(ls, .id = 'x') %>%
   column_to_rownames('x') %>%
   t
   a  b  c
a  1 NA  1
b  2  2  2
d  2 NA NA
c NA  3 NA
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
xtabs(values ~ ind + x, do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, x = names(ls), lapply(ls, stack))))
   x
ind a b c
  a 1 0 1
  b 2 2 2
  d 2 0 0
  c 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `rbindlist`

```
> t(rbindlist(Map(function(x) data.table(t(x)), lst), fill = TRUE))
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1   NA    1
b    2    2    2
d    2   NA   NA
c   NA    3   NA
```